# redirecting to the originating server

Tags: linux, ssh, redirection, redirect

The following is working as expected. The only problem is that it does not return the source server command prompt unless I hit Ctrl + c

```
[abc@server]$ 0</dev/null echo "ls" | ssh  -t -t abc@10.10.10.124 "sh"
tcgetattr: Invalid argument
sh-3.2$ xyz.tar.gz
sh-3.2$ Killed by signal 2.
[abc@server]$
```

I want to use it in shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not:

```
$ ssh -t -t abc@10.10.10.124 'ls && exit'
```

---

> The actual command is `echo "file.txt" | ssh -t -t` ...

I think you mean `cat file.txt` (`file.txt` contains all the commands which you want to execute on the remote server), and if so, just append `exit` to the end of this file:

```
$ sed '$a exit' file.txt | ssh -t -t abc@10.10.10.124
```

- `$` is used to indicate the last line
- `a` stands for append

Comment: It is part of shell script. The actual command is echo "file.txt" | ssh -t -t ... # Update: I can change echo to standard in < # got it # thanks

Comment: I still have to use ctrl + C to get out of the prompt. Any other tip?

Comment: check out my updated answer.

Comment: brilliant answer.